# Ways to learn Antilife shell on a Necromancy wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, necromancy

Is there a RAW way to learn the spell Antilife shell on a wizard of the necromancy school without taking more than 3 levels of any other class? Any feats or magic items or features that would make that possible? The spell feels like it could be really good on a necromancer.

Comment: Are you sure you want to cast it while still alive?

Comment: @Joshua I haven't found a way to cast while dead so far, so yes.

Comment: It seems like it should immediately exclude your body from the shell, quite possibly breaking it into several pieces in the process and sending them different ways. Even if it doesn't exclude you, any internal parasites you have are going to be projectiles breaking out of your body.

Comment: @Joshua hm I can see your point but that is generally about the spell and has nothing to do with my question, right? Because afaik there would then be no way for PCs to cast it. So im pretty sure my DM will allow it to not affect me. You could make a separate question about the spell if you want ;)

Comment: vampire PCs are a thing.

Comment: @joshua I did not know that, but a short search seems to indicate that the pc vampire races in Zendikar and Ixalan are not undead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Dwarf (Mark of Warding) accomplishes this

This is a character creation option from *Eberron Rising from the Last War*. This adds the *antilife shell* spell (and others) to your spell list if you have either the Spellcasting or Pact Magic feature which a Wizard certainly does.